# Evaluating AppFabric and have some newbie questions like why does setting up AppFabric require a database or xml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, appfabric, distributed-caching

I'm new to AppFabric and I'm evaluating a distributed cache solution for a production environment and I'm in a Microsoft shop using Asp.net MVC and WebApi, and we are not using Windows Azure.

In setting up AppFabric on my local computer, there was a step to create a database or use xml, I'd like to understand the concept here.  Is AppFabri depending on a datasource (db or xml files) to persist?  If so, wouldn't this be a potential bottleneck?

Also, could anyone who is using AppFabric right now on their production servers comment on their experience using it?  Any pitfalls or gotchas?

Thanks, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

I can give you my experience from a little over a year ago after deploying AppFabric in a production environment.  I haven't kept up with it since because my experience wasn't great.  Maybe they've fixed some of the issues we had.

The step to create a database or XML is just to store configuration information for the cluster.

My notes (remember this was current a year ago, so maybe things have changed):

1. When caching an object from C#, the object was turned into XML and stored. It was a verbose format and made storing/getting a little slower than it should have been. I would have rather had the object serialized to a binary format - or compressed - or just anything other than uncompressed XML.  We actually modified our objects to have shorter property names when cached since they turned into XML.  This caused some objects to go from 1MB down to a couple hundred kilobytes.
2. AppFabric was communicating over the NetTcp protocol in Windows and this caused us some grief.  We had some servers without the Windows service installed (NetTcp) and that caused headaches.  We couldn't figure out why AppFabric worked on one machine and not another.
3. It did seem to do well with distributing the load across multiple machines in the cluster. It also seemed to retrieve stuff fast and the expiration logic always worked fine.
4. At the time it was just a fairly immature product.  We couldn't find any support anywhere for it.  I remember being on the phone with Microsoft trying to track down some issues we had and every time the person would say, "AppFabric?  What is that?"  The community around it at the time was non-existent.  (This was *really* painful for us.)

If I had to do an application for Windows that needed a distributed cache I would have to re-evaluate AppFabric.  My first experience wasn't the greatest.  Now I'd think of Redis, Couchbase, Memcached - in that order.

Comment: In AppFabric 1.1, there is support for compression, but it's set for a cache client, not the cache itself - see the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351483.aspx).

Comment: The documentation for commpression is flaky at best - where do you add this setting? Do you add it to your client's web.config or the xml config on the host?